# insert current date into text document while editing it in Kate

Tags: kde, editors, kate

I would like to insert the current date into an open Kate text document while editing it by using a shortcut key combination.

I see several such options for Atom, but I don't find anything for Kate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have that functionality globally, you could use `xdotool` for this.

In my setup I have a shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
xdotool type $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)
```

which I bind to a global hotkey.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "$(date +%F)"
```

Save that as an executable somewhere, and then:

- Go to Settings > Configure Kate > External Tools
- Click `Add > Add Tool`
- Set `Name` to a name of your liking
- Set `Executable` to `/path/to/script`
- For `Output` I used `Insert at Cursor Position`
- Set up a shortcut key for it.

Comment: This is the right answer. That xdotool trick from kai-dj is doing something really weird, but this approach is kate specific and works 100%

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use external scripts in this case.
Go to `Tools` > `External Tools` > `Configure...`, the press <kbd>Add</kbd> > `Add tool...`

- Set `Name:` to a name, say, `Insert date`.
- Press empty button and choose an icon of your liking, for example, `view-calendar` in `Actions` group.
- Set `Executable:` to `echo`.
- Set `Arguments:` to `-n %{Date:dd.MM.yy}`, for example. `-n` prevents line feed for `echo` command, `%{Date:}` is internal Kate variable.
- Switch `Output` to `Insert at Cursor Position`.

Press <kbd>OK</kbd>, then <kbd>Apply</kbd>. That's it.

You can check available date formats using this [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdate.html#toString).
More info regarding Kate External Tools can be found [here](https://kate-editor.org/post/2019/2019-09-21-external-tools-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

To do that, I am using AutoKey App,
setting a ++d
to run this script

```
output = system.exec_command("date +%Y-%m-%d")
keyboard.send_keys(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

`xdotool` was already mentioned in the [answer by @kay-dj](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451400/377345), but this only works on `X11`.

However, there is a variant [`ydotool`](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool) that works also on wayland.

```
#!/bin/sh
ydotool type $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)
```

I am using GNOME (currently 43) on Wayland, Manjaro and I use GNOME custom shortcuts to define global key for this script like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Type `F7` key to open the command line, then `date` in the command line and return, as per [this documentation](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/katepart/advanced-editing-tools-commandline.html).